# How to homogenize date type in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a Date column in my dataframe having dates with 2 different types (YYYY-DD-MM 00:00:00 and YYYY-DD-MM) :

```
                        Date
0        2023-01-10 00:00:00
1                 2024-27-06
2        2022-07-04 00:00:00
3                        NaN
4                 2020-30-06
```

(you can use pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+') after copying the previous dataframe to get it in your notebook)

I would like to have only a YYYY-MM-DD type. Consequently, I would like to have :

```
                        Date
0                 2023-10-01
1                 2024-06-27
2                 2022-04-07
3                        NaN
4                 2020-06-30
```

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `format` parameter:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace(' 00:00:00',''), format='%Y-%d-%m')
print (df)

        Date
0 2023-10-01
1 2024-06-27
2 2022-04-07
3        NaT
4 2020-06-30
```

Another idea with match both formats:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m 00:00:00', errors='coerce')

df['Date'] = d1.fillna(d2)
```